# NullPointerException when accessing a static field

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

As they say System is final class which have out of type PrintStream as a field member and println is method in PrintStream class.

I created a class `UseNumber` with static field no of type `Number` and just wanted to access a method of Number class but it is throwing `NullPointerException`

```
public class Number {

    private int first;
    private int second;


    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(int second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

}
```

and for UseNumber Class

```
public class UseNumber {
    private static Number no;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UseNumber.no.setFirst(12); //throwing nullpointer exception here
        UseNumber.no.setSecond(22);
        System.out.println(UseNumber.no.getFirst()+UseNumber.no.getSecond());

    }


}
```

Comment: what I see: you should create an instance of that class first. Secondly, you should always offer a constructor doing those setters in one step. And why did you name your object "UseNumber.no"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Re: NullPointerException

`setFirst` is **not** a static method and it requires an instance of Number. You didn't create one. You just declared a Number variable called `no`. Since it's initialized to null by default, you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

One way to fix it:

```
private static Number no = new Number();
```

The variable `no` being declared as static inside UseNumber simply means you will be able to access this object *without* an instance of UseNumber. But this static declaration won't cascade down to the methods of `no`. They will still require an instance, as emphasized by the error you're getting.

### Re: System.out

`out` is a static member of `System` - but it's an *instantiated* object already.

In fact, if you view the code of `System`, you'll find this line:

```
out = com.ibm.jvm.io.ConsolePrintStream.localize(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)), true);
```

So when you say:

```
System.out
```

*System* will give you the its initialized PrintStream object called *out*. In essence, `System.out.println` is just a shortcut for this:

```
PrintStream p = System.out;
p.println();
```

Comment: ok got it but as i told i was trying to understand concept behind S.O.P in that context neither did print method in PrintStream Class is static

Comment: @user2037489 I have revised my answer to include the explanation about SOP. I hope it's enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

A nullpointerException is thrown when you attempt to access a null object by the "." operator.
In the line you indicated the exception is thrown, the no object is null and you are trying to access its setFirst method which will of course throw a nullpointer exception.

to fix the error, initialize your no object, maybe like this :

```
public class UseNumber {
private static Number no;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UseNumber.no = new Number(); // Initialize here your no object 
    UseNumber.no.setFirst(12); //This line will no longer throw an exception.
    UseNumber.no.setSecond(22);
    System.out.println(UseNumber.no.getFirst()+UseNumber.no.getSecond());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a interface method to get the instance of no. In the method you can check if it's null, similar to the way we do with Singleton pattern.

```
public class UseNumber {
 private static Number no;
 public static getNumberInstance() {
      if(no == NULL) {
         no = new Number(); //This will get executed only once, for first call.
      }
     return no;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    UseNumber.getNumberInstance().setFirst(12); 
    UseNumber.getNumberInstance().setSecond(22);
    System.out.println(UseNumber.getNumberInstance().getFirst() 
       +UseNumber.getNumberInstance().getSecond());

  }
}
```